# How to write test cases for jersey api using Junit for testing the api response and parameters?

Tags: junit, jersey, spring-boot

This is my api i have used Jersey and spring boot.The api is working fine producing correct response and I want to write unit test case for checking api using Junit.

```
@POST
    @Path("/trip/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrip(Trip pObjTrip, @HeaderParam("Auth-Token") String pAuthToken) {
        Response lRetVal = new Response();
        appLog.info(String.format("Creating a trip with [%s]", pObjTrip));

        try {
            User lObjUser = validateUser(pAuthToken, lRetVal);
            if(lObjUser == null) {
            } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(pObjTrip.getTripName())) {
                lRetVal.setResult(ResponseIds.API_RESULT_INSUFFICIENT_INFO);
                lRetVal.setMessage("All information are not provided");
            } else {
                lObjUser.setEnabled(true);
                pObjTrip.setCreatedBy(lObjUser);
                pObjTrip.setCreateTime(Calendar.getInstance());
                pObjTrip.setTripStatus(Trip.TRIP_STATUS_CREATED);
                m_cObjTripService.saveAndFlush(pObjTrip);
                lRetVal.setResult(ResponseIds.API_RESULT_SUCCESS);
                lRetVal.setValue(pObjTrip);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            appLog.warn(ex.toString(), ex);
        }
        return lRetVal;
    }
```

I have written the test case after searching But getting 400 bad request for(http://localhost:8080/api/trphpr/trip/create).

```
@After(value = "http://localhost:8080/api/trphpr/trip/create")
    public void testCreateTripApi() throws IOException{



MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(2);
          map.add("tripNme", "test trip");    

          org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders lhttpheader = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();          
          lhttpheader.add("Auth-Token", "7f8b655a007dda8f93a77fcb44de3298efb67615a5585b2fdc6c95b4cc2c4a52282deae6119a2fd6c3f9b4e3723e3d1cb221376ed36d978f0ff31b585d8e70f4");
          lhttpheader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

          List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
          msgConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
          restTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverters);

          HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, lhttpheader);

          Response apiResponse = (Response) restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/trphpr/trip/create", request, Response.class);

          assertNotNull(apiResponse);

          //Asserting the response of the API.
          String message = apiResponse.getMessage();
          Trip ltrip = (Trip)apiResponse.getValue();

          assertEquals("trip created successfully", message);
          assertEquals("trip test", ltrip.getTripName());
        }
}
```

Comment: Please check [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

Comment: @Abhishek- I would have gone through this Jersey Test Framework but i couldn't get solution.